# React Router only rendering one route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-dom

I am new to React and react-router-dom.  I have spent a couple hours now and I'm just hitting dead ends.

I'm using create-react-app and bulma for css. My dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "bulma": "^0.7.1",
  "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
  "node-sass-chokidar": "^1.3.3",
  "react": "^16.5.2",
  "react-bulma-components": "^2.1.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
  "react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
  "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
  "react-scripts": "2.0.4"
```

},

I've looked at all the related questions on stackoverflow, create-react-app documentation and searched their open issues section in their repo, googled every possible keyword. I'm at a loss.

My router will only render one route (Homeroute).

**How do I get this to show '/create' route as well?**

I've tried:

- combinations of 'exact' and 'strict' attributes
- wrapped everything after <BrowserRouter> or <HashRouter> with a <div>
- tried both (un)wrapping <Route> with <Switch>
- tried both BrowserRouter and HashRouter

  ```
  import React, { Component } from "react";
  import { Switch, Route, NavLink, BrowserRouter, HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";

  const Home = () => {
      return (<h2>This is Home</h2>);
  }
  const Create = () => {
      return (<h2>This is Create page</h2>);
  }

  class App extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <HashRouter>
          <div>
            <Navigation />
            <div className="section">
              <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                <Route path="/create" exact Component={Create} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </HashRouter>
      );
    }
  }
  export default App;
  ```

URL: http://localhost:3000/#/

Result:  "This is Home"

Expect:  "This is Home"

URL: http://localhost:3000/#/create

URL: http://localhost:3000/#/create/

Result:   *nothing*

Expect:  "This is Create page"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a typo. Notice the letter "C", it's supposed to be lower-case.

Make a change, from

```js
<Route path="/create" exact Component={Create} />
```

to

```js
<Route path="/create" exact component={Create} />
```

This is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/oq0rov0r4q